# Parse String with Regex c#

Tags: c#, parsing, devexpress

I am trying to customise a DevExpress grid filter.

Currently I return the data from my api, and so I need to parse the built in string which is returned from the grid.

An example of the filter string is;

> StartsWith([name], 'test') And StartsWith([quantity], '12') And
>   StartsWith([id], '1') And StartsWith([date], '01/10/2015')

I would like to convert this to a Dictionary in the most efficient way?

Comment: Please do not ask several questions in one post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Regex for filtering the key/value pair outta your string and a simple foreach to prepare the dictionary.

This could be a solution:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> FilterAPIData(string data)
    {
        var r = new Regex(@"\[\w+\], \'[\w/]+\'");

        var result = r.Matches(data);
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (Match item in result)
        {
            var val = item.Value.Split(',');
            dict.Add(val[0], val[1]);
        }

        return dict;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be the best option for this, but I'll show you how to do it without Regex as it can be a bit difficult to understand.

Assuming your string will always be in this format you can do this:

```
string str = "StartsWith([name], 'test') And StartsWith([quantity], '12') And StartsWith([id], '1') And StartsWith([date], '01/10/2015')";
var strArray = str.Split(new string[]{"And "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var value in strArray)
{
    dict.Add(GetStringBetween(value, "[", "]"), GetStringBetween(value, "'", "'"));
}

private string GetStringBetween(string value, string startDelim, string endDelim)
{
     int first = value.IndexOf(startDelim) + startDelim.Length;
     int last = value.LastIndexOf(endDelim);

     return value.Substring(first, last - first);
}

//Output : 
//name test 
//quantity 12 
//id 1 
// date 01/10/2015
```

If there other formats the string can be in you can adjust as needed. I would also consider adding in more validation/error handling, but I will let you figure that out ;)

Comment: Hi thats great, I am happy to use a regex as it'll bemore efficient. How would it be done in this case please?

Comment: We're not here to give you lessons on regex. The best way to learn is to research. Also, a great website to help is regexr.com or regex101.com. These websites give you "cheat sheets" on how to use regex keywords and also have dynamic results view making it very easy to test your expressions.  Also this solution isn't "inefficient". There will be no noticeable difference on performance compared to regex.

Comment: How does this approach sound? use a regex to strip out all the un-needed strings Regex("StartsWith([|]|)") and use this to replace it with "". Maybe then replace the  ',' with '=' and 'And' with ',' I suppose I would be using a few regex commands in this case are these more effeicient than the above?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn There's no reason to use more than one expression ;) Take a look at Vitor's answer, copy that expression to regexr.com and play with it and try to understand how it works.

Comment: Absolutely. Remember, don't just take an answer and go with it. Always try to understand how and why it works. After some time, you will start seeing patterns on how problems are solved and will be able to figure these things out on your own. ;)